# How to Use RadWindow as MainWindow of WPF application

Tags: wpf, telerik, mainwindow, radwindow

I want to use RadWindow as the main window of my WPF application. So that outer window also take the theme of overall application. I used [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/radwindow-as-main-window.aspx) approach, but after that application is not being shown on Taskbar anymore. After reading different threads I came to know that because RadWindow is not child of Window so that's why its not possible.

So What is now I am trying to do, is to hide the outer Window completely **somehow** and to use RadWindow as a child, but parent of all other controls. Following is XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <telerik:RadWindow WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="MyRadWindow">
    <Grid>
      <!-- All Controls here -->
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadWindow>
</Window>
```

But I am unable to completely hide the outer window. It still shows the borders. Then as a second step I have to handle the minimize, maximize and window close events from this `RadWidow`.

If anyone have tried this approach please help me out or suggest what would be the better way of doing this?

**The main purpose of doing all this is to Sync the GUI of Outerwindow with the current TelerikTheme.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to set main class as telerik window instead of nesting inside normal window:

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="MyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="True"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
      <!-- All Controls here -->
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Don't forget to change base class of MyTest.MainWindow to RadWindow

EDIT: Sorry didn't notice provided link.
You can try hide main window with overriding it style by setting following attributes:

```
WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency ="True"
```

Comment: Thanks @vadim, for your your suggestions, it is creating a chrome-less window as per my requirement, but how the Resize, Maximize and Minimize functionality will work?

Comment: As you overriding default style you have to provide this functionality by yourself. Maybe nested RadWindow can help with that? Also I think you should try to find solution of showing RadWindow in Taskbar instead of using it as nested window.

Comment: I am going forward with nested window approach, as `RadWindow` is not of `Window` type, so framework will not accept it as a `Window`. Telerik has also mentioned that `RadWindow` is not designed to be the parent window.

Comment: After spending some time, and few hit an tries I successfully implemented the required scenario, Thanks @vadim, your suggestion worked for me, and I used the approach suggested by you. I was able to show the `RadWindow` in taskbar, `RadWindow` when used as parent window uses `Window` as its parent which is **chromeless**, so all you need to do is to get the instance of that window using `ParentOfType<Window>()` and show it in task bar.

Comment: With the latest Telerik controls use the RadWindowInteropHelper solution described in ThorstenHa's answer below.

Comment: RadWindow doesn't provide a WindowStyle property.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler solution using the RadWindowInteropHelper like this:

```
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;
public partial class MyRadWindow : RadWindow
{
    public MyRadWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RadWindowInteropHelper.SetShowInTaskbar(this, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can also be done in xaml: 

xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.ShowInTaskbar="True"

see: http://celticcodingsolutions.com/Blog/post/2014/05/22/Usikng-Telerik-WPF-RadWindow-as-MainWindow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. First open the MainWindow.xaml file and replace the Window declaration with RadWindow declaration:
   `<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="RadWindowAsMainWindow.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
   Loaded="RadWindow_Loaded_1"
   Header="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">`
   ...
   `</telerik:RadWindow>`

and in code-behind:
    `

```
public partial class MainWindow : RadWindow
    {
     ...
    }
```

`2.  Then override OnStartup method of the Application class to show the RadWindow:`

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
```

`

1. Then in RadWindowLoad event write this:
   `

   private void RadWindow_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               var window = this.ParentOfType();
               window.ShowInTaskbar = true;
           }

`